# Saving XML file with Azure

Tags: azure

I have an XML file that I'm saving on my local machine (Windows 8).

I want to allow the application to push that XML up to Azure.  Then I would also need the ability to recall it as a sync process.

I'm not sure what services I need and if Azure would even provide it.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to use the Azure Storage Blob. Push the XML file as BLOB in your Azure Storage Blob, you will get/have a URL to access that.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I'm looking at the Azure site now and I have no idea where the "Storage Blob" is.  Do you have a link that takes me to it?

Comment: @JeffV Here is the link you can follow
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/

Comment: Wow that looks like it is everything I need!  Thank you so much for the info.